# Failed to load module pytesseract

Tags: python-2.7, python-tesseract

I am trying capture text file from image and I am referring to this link https://www.simplifiedpython.net/how-to-extract-text-from-image-in-python/

So far I already done installing the pytesseract and Image library using this command:

```
pip install Image
pip install pytesseract
```

Already done downloading and install the PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe

I tried now to run this on my script but still got error:

```
import pytesseract
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
```

Here is my error:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Anyone know if there any prerequisites that I am missing now. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall the numpy and error got solve.